# When and how does m2e use the Maven test scope to include test dependencies in Eclipse Run Configurations?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

It took me a while to make this observation, but I see that m2e "magically" manages the classpath.

Examples:
If I Run as a Java application in the "src/java/main" source folder it excludes "test" scope.  Note: The class was able to compile, but not able to run.  But if I move that same class to the "src/java/test" folder then it is able to compile and run.

If I `Run as JUnit Test` then the "test" scope is always included (even if the class is in the "main" source folder).

The only way I made these discover is by dumping the java.class.path system property at runtime.

I found the following at http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-faq.html

> Also note, that classpath used for JUnit and Java Application launch
>   configurations for projects that have Maven support enabled is also
>   calculated in a special way and excluded resources does not affect it
>   either.

I cannot see any differences when I compare their Run Configurations, so how can I see what magic is being performed?
And is there a way to override the "normal" behavior via the Run Configuration or any other means?

Comment: I am able to see all the resolved dependencies of the pom.xml (even the test scope) when i open the Dependency Hierarchy.  m2e might change class path according to what you are running.

Comment: Why do you want to change the run configurations? Wouldn't it be better to try to repair the problem in Maven? What is your runtime error?

Comment: @JFMeier My runtime error is NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException.  There is nothing wrong with my maven configuration.  After I thought of this some more, I think that m2e should improve the Run Configuration to make it more visible to the user what the classpath will be at runtime.  Now it just shows "Maven Dependencies".  If you look at "Maven Dependencies" in Package Explorer it appears to include all of the jars in "test" scope (not 100% sure of this), which in my case, definitely includes the jar with the class that is missing at runtime.

Comment: @ravthiru I've seen the Dependency Hierarchy and that is very useful.  Maybe the Run Configuration would be more clear if it showed the scope that will actually be used at runtime, like "Maven Dependencies [test]" or "Maven Dependencies [compile+runtime]".  Showing the jars and/or linking to the correct view in the Dependency Hierarchy (if possible) would be a plus.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=410228:

> Here is how m2e decides if java application launch should use test or runtime artifact scopes.
>
> - "run as junit test" and "run as testng test" uses test scope.
> - "run as java application" uses test scope if application main class is located under src/test/java, otherwise uses runtime scope.

This means you can control the behavior using the location of the main class.