# How to create a launch configuration "Java Application" that uses Maven Dependencies from scope=test for its classpath?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

This question is a bit related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031421/when-and-how-does-m2e-use-the-maven-test-scope-to-include-test-dependencies-in-e) one.

### Problem Description

I want to create a new Launch Configuration of type "Java Application" (not JUnit!) that will start some kind of stand-alone test tool that we have.

This test tool is also needed during the Maven Build phase integration-test and is therefore included in the `pom.xml`. However, the dependency is in `<scope>test</scope>`.

The problem is that the Maven Dependencies which I add to the classpath of my launch configuration does not contain the dependency to this test tool library which makes it obviously impossible to e.g. find the MainClass that shall be run.

### Question

Is it possible to create a launch configuration that uses the Maven Dependencies of the scope "test"?

### Remarks

Note, that I do not want to create a "Maven Build" launch config as I want to run the test tool as a stand-alone Java application.

---

**EDIT**

### "Solution"

I ended up creating a JUnit Test case that does nothing but calling the main method of the stand-alone application. It is very dirty but it gets the job done.

Comment: You should put the "solution" as an answer below, not edit your original question.

Comment: It's not a real solution to my original question though. It is merely a workaround that is okay for me.

Comment: It may not be the solution, but it is a solution. Others might improve on it. As it is, a question with zero answers is going to get ranked pretty low in searches.